# How to remove the default UISearchBar len?

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar

I was looking for this for a while & I can't find anything about it!
How can I remove/hide this len, in the left on the searchBar Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean lense as in the magnifying glass? The UISearchBar has a standard design so that users recognize search UI in any application. If your not using it for search I wouldn't use something called UISearchBar. If you are using it for search I wouldn't remove the magnifying glass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not supported but the UISearchBar, however you can screen capture the UISearchBar and remove the magnifying glass with some image editing tool and then use this image with a UIButton and mimic the functionality of the UISearchBar.